# AsyncTask - How to keep onPostExecute and onPreExecute from interfering each other in subsquent calls?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a problem with my `AsyncTask`.
I make the ProgressBar visible in `onPreExecute` and invisible in `onPostExecute`. This works properly for 1 call in a row or if I wait before the last one is finished. But when I start multiple of these AsyncTasks in a row, the `onPostExecute` of the last one seems to be called AFTER `onPreExecute` of the next one, causing the ProgressBar to be invisible. Any idea what I could do?

```
private static class ExampleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> activityReference;

    ExampleAsyncTask(MainActivity context) {
        activityReference = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
        Log.i("TAG", "doInBackground started");
        for (int i = 1; i < integers[0]; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            publishProgress((i * 100) / integers[0]);
        }

        return "Finished";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
        if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
            return;
        }

        activity.progressBar.setProgress(0);
        activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(activity, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use multiple `AsyncTask`'s in a row? Remove `setVisibility` from the task since `onPre` and `onPost` all execute on the UI thread anyway. How are you using these "in a row"?

Comment: You should give each async task its own progress bar.

Comment: This is just an example for practicing. Are there no real life cases where we would create and call such an AsyncTask multiple times in a row?

Comment: It is also unclear what your progressbar would indicate. The progress for one task? Or a total for all tasks? Difficult helping if we dont know.

Comment: The progress for 1 task

Comment: Well then give every asynctask its own progress bar. You dont need that weekreference then. Life suddenly becomes easy.

Comment: It's just the same AsyncTask as often as I click the button.

Comment: Thats ok of course. Well than put the progress bar in the async task class. Not in your activity. It is pretty normal that a progressbar is a member of the asynctask. Look at asynctask examples.

Comment: I just thought it is a common pattern to handle the ProgressBar like this. I dont understand why onPostExecuted of task 1 is called after onPreExecute of task 2

Comment: Are you trying to use the `ProgressBar` in each item of a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`?

Comment: No, its just in an Activity with 1 Button and 1 ProgressBar. Its just for practicing purposes to understand it

Comment: If you start five of your async tasks at the same time then all five constructors and onPreExecutes() can be called right away. After that the doInBackground()s will run one after another.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand!

Answer (score 0):

I have one pretty easy solution guys. Just use counter. At starting keep your counter 0.

**EXPLAINATION**

When you are making your progressbar visible, every time increment your counter by 1. In onPostExecute method just decrement your counter by 1 and check for counter. if it's 0 then make your progressbar invisible.

**SOLUTION CODE:**
      int counter  =0; // field defined inside class

```
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            MainActivity activity = activityReference.get();
            if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }
            counter = counter + 1;
            activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        ....
        ....
        ....
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        counter--;
        if(counter == 0)//there is no active background tasks
        {
        activity.progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ....// do what you want 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to use the progressBar to display the progress for all your tasks, it doesn't make sense to have a single progressbar for all of them if you are running them in parallel. Depending on when each task finishes, they will keep changing the progress bar. Either have separate progressbars for your tasks or run your tasks in series. You can run your asyncTasks in series using this:

```
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);
```

Note: minimum API level to use this is 11